# Flex 4.6 Mobile: How to move active view and put a menu behind it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.6

I have a ViewNavigatorApplication in Flex 4.6 and I wish to implement an application menu which is very similar to the one in the Facebook mobile app.

Specifically:

- When the menu button is pressed, the main menu is created and placed behind the current view.
- The current view (there are lots of views in the app), gets moved to the left to reveal the menu behind it.
- When the menu is closed the view gets moved back into default position (left=0) and then the main menu is removed from the screen to save processing power.

I figured out how to move the current view out of the way by using the "navigator.activeView.left" property, but I cannot figure out how to add the menu to the screen. I've tried adding it to the global stage object but it doesn't show up on the screen.

Does anyone know a simple way to tackle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess that won't be practical much because flex mobile is based on views and you can't have anything outside the views. So if you use "navigator.activeView.left" to move the whole view, you simply can't replace the empty space with anything else.

The workaround can be (I haven't tried):
Adding two VGROUP inside a HGROUP where menu on the 1st vgroup with 100% height and rest of the content on the 2nd vgroup. This way initially you can hide the men and on Menu action trigger, you can move 2nd vgroup(content) to the right amount of space and make menu visible.

Possible algorithm:

```
<hgroup width='100%' height='100%'>
  <vgroup width='20%' visible='false' includeInLayout='fasle'>Menu here</vgroup>
  <vgroup width='80%'>Menu here</vgroup>
</hgroup>
```

Please rewrite this code as I was just typing from my mind. It's been a while I used mxml last.

Best wishes